# How to convert an assemblies BAML to XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, baml

How do I walk through an assemblies BAML resources and convert them back to XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BamlViewer plugin for Reflector does exactly that, you might want to have a look at the code on CodePlex: http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BamlViewer

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to Reflector is **ILSpy**, which is free and open source. It can decompile BAML files to XAML.